# Calling another function within Angular gridOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

I have created a `dateTime` function as below within my controller:

```
    $scope.getDatetime = function() {
        return (new Date()).toLocaleFormat("%A, %B %e, %Y") + "name.csv" ;
    };
```

I am using `gridOptions` as below

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
        exporterCsvFilename: 'getDatetime()',
        exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'Field1' },
            { field: 'Field1' }
        ]
    };
```

Using the above syntax, the file is downloading with name as `getDatetime().csv` instead of displaying the actual date

Comment: The non-standard Date.prototype.toLocaleFormat method is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It uses a format string in the same format expected by the strftime() function in C. The function is no longer available in Firefox 58+. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_toLocaleFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give single quotes, if you give single quotes it will consider as a string

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            exporterCsvFilename:$scope.getDatetime(),//call the function
            exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
            columnDefs: [
                { field: 'Field1' },
                { field: 'Field1' }
            ]
        };
```